How to reflect (mirror) hijack/sendInput a mouse, windows?
I need to reflect mouse by x-asis (and change sensitivity)
replace left/right to right/left in windows
but usage of sendInput and setCursorPos is not working in some full screen apps
(and probably just sending double reflected input is not the best in terms on optimization for production)
I have noticed some synapsis touchpad drivers allow reflect function natively
some don't
the device I'm making this app will always have the same hardware, and the same mouse/touchapd driver I'm gonna choose
are there any official drivers that allow to take control over mouse using ioctl? or maybe is there similar function in windows accessibility features?

Are you mixing C and C++ languages?  The C++ language allows for operator overloading, namespaces, which makes linking C++ with C language tricky.  Much simpler to stick to C or C++ language.
